# Hadoop Pig "Load" issue when loading a csv file whose value field contains comma and a special character

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a csv file  whose sample data looks like this..

 Name , JOB , Salary  
------------------------- 
 Jack ,  IT  , $12,00 
-------------------------
 John , HR  , $24,00 
--------------------------

when I load this data using this command 
`A = LOAD '/USER/XYZ/PIG/FILENAME.CSV' USING PIGSTORAGE(',') as (NAME:chararray,JOB:chararray, Salary:chararray) ;`

the comma in "$12,00" is considered as delimiting character, only $12 is being loaded. 
Is there any workaround for this? 
and is it possible to load the salary field as integer (ignoring the '$' sign too)..

Comment: so your delimter is " |" why dont you use "|" as delimiter.

Comment: well, just for representation purpose..i added a table like structure in the question. Actually , comma is the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below:

1. Isntead of using PigStorage use, `org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage()`
2. Instead of using **chararray**, specify datatype of salary as **float**.

Answer (score 0):

Load the file using "|" as the delimiter.For the $ sign use the REPLACE command and then cast the field to int

```
A = LOAD '/USER/XYZ/PIG/FILENAME.CSV' USING PIGSTORAGE('|') as (NAME:chararray,JOB:chararray, Salary:chararray) ;
A1 = FOREACH A GENERATE NAME,JOB,(int)REPLACE(Salary,'([^a-zA-Z0-9.,\\s]+)','');
```